# Paying tax on monetary gifts

Tags: united-states, taxes, income, gifts

I live in Wisconsin and received $5,000 from a living relative as a one-time gift.  Do I need to report this on my income taxes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not. Gifts are taxed to the donor, and the first $14000 per year per donor per recipient are exempt.